# Google Sites not Allowing Owner to See Changes or Edit from Side Bar

Tags: google-workspace, google-sites

I am the owner/creator of a google site (https://sites.google.com/nottowayschools.org/nottowaynews/home). I have made my assistant an editor. She has made changes to the site; however, I cannot see the changes. Also, I previously was able to make edits using the side bar (insert/pages/themes) but now I cannot make changes or maneuver through the pages from the side bar. This problem also is true for a second site I am the owner/creator of - that I've since disabled because I was unable to make edits. I've checked my permissions and I don't see anything that has changed. Why am I unable to see changes to the site made by the editor and why am I unable to maneuver through the site using the side bar?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Is it alright if you can include some screenshots on your post that shows the options on the side bar being grayed out? Also, may I ask if you have already reached out with [Google Workspace support?](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: None of us can log into your account and check whether or not your sidebar is working.  You need to contact Google's support.